# can the swith construct be nested inside an (if-else ) construct or vice versa?

Tags: java

I wrote this code to calculate the valid day entry---- and in the process i experimented with nesting the switch statement inside the if else statement... in the switch statement.. i further added an if else statement...

And was pretty happy.. with it.. until i .. well.. **Compiled it** :(

it's giving like 50 errors.. or something... So is this type of nesting invalid??
What all nesting is valid?

*The code is as follows*

```
      public DateFour(int m,int d,int y){

      if (y<2011 && y>0){
          year=y;
          if{
              switch(m){
              case 1:case 3 case 5: case 7:case 8:case 10: case 12:
                 month=31;
                 if (day>0 && day<=31){
                 day=d;
                 System.out.println("The date today is:"+day"/"+month+"/"+year);
                  }
                  else{
                      System.out.println("invalid date");
                  }
                  break;
                 case 2:
                             month=28;
                              if (day>0 && day<=28){
                 day=d;
                 System.out.println("The date today is:"+day"/"+month+"/"+year);
                  }
                  else{
                      System.out.println("invalid date");
                  }
                             break;
                             case 4:
                             case 6:
                             case 9:
                             case 11:
                             month =30;
                              if (day>0 && day<=30){
                 day=d;
                 System.out.println("The date today is:"+day"/"+month+"/"+year);
                  }
                  else{
                      System.out.println("invalid date");
                  }
                             default:
                             System.out.println("Invalid month.");

                  }


      }
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("invalid input");

  }
  }
```

Comment: `if{ ` is this if statement ?

Comment: In cases like this it helps if you indent your code correctly. IDE's like eclipse can do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if {
```

That is not a valid construct in Java. `if` what?

```
case 1:case 3 case 5: case 7:case 8:case 10: case 12:
```

You're missing a `:` in there. Please use spacing consistently.

All your print statements are missing a `+` after `day`.

Otherwise, yes, you can nest switch and if. It just gets unreadable very, very fast (as you have just noticed).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the others have determined all of your syntax errors, you also may have a logic error setting month=(max days in that month) when it should be set to m.  You are already catching invalid days in your next statement.

Answer (score 0):

yes nesting a switch and and if else is possible. since your progrm has already been debugged i would just advise you to space out your coding better as this will help you in debugging it more easily.